# lambda function to query DynamoDB present in another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am wondering if we can write a lambda function in one region for example us-east-1 to query a DynamoDB database present in another region.

I feel that there is a provision.
just wondering how the syntax would be to achieve this.

```
dynamo_client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
dynamo_table = dynamo_client.Table('table')
```

Above is a normal example of a dynamodb connection in the same region.

Wondering how would be the syntax when we want to access the dynamodb from another region.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. [resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.resource) takes `region_name` parameter:

```
dynamo_client = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='<your-other-regio>')
dynamo_table = dynamo_client.Table('table')
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. In your Lambda code - you can still set the Region for the DynamoDB Service Client. Consider this Java example:

```
// Create a DynamoDbClient object
 Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
 DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .build();
```

Now you can interact with a DynamoDB table located in US-WEST_2 region.